# Unable to get log file to save

Tags: python, logging

Using python, I am unable to get my log file to save.

```
import logging
from datetime import datetime
#Open a log file to save diagnostic data
TODAY = datetime.now() #get current date and time
DAY = TODAY.strftime("%d") #format day as string
MONTH = TODAY.strftime("%m") #format month as string
YEAR = TODAY.strftime("%y") #format year as string
HOUR = TODAY.strftime("%H") #format hour as string
MINUTE = TODAY.strftime("%M") #format minute as string
LOG_FILE = MONTH + "-" + DAY + "-" + YEAR + "-H" + HOUR + "-M" + MINUTE + ".log"
logging.basicConfig(filename=LOG_FILE, level=logging.DEBUG)
logging.debug('Test message')
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong

edit: No debug message is printed to the console. Basically this script currently does nothing.

update: Looks like the script runs fine on my raspberry pi, but not on my macbook. Perhaps it is an issue with default handlers?

Comment: What happens? Do you get an error message? (Please edit into your question.)

Comment: Pro tip: Just use `LOG_FILE = TODAY.strftime("%m-%d-%y-H%H-M%M.log")`.

Comment: How do you run this code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python does not create log file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26237870/python-does-not-create-log-file)

Comment: You only add a `FileHandler` to the root logger with `basicConfig`, so it only outputs to file. For console, you need to create a `StreamHandler` and add it to the root logger too.